# Add space above algorithm2e

Tags: spacing, margins, overleaf, algorithm2e

I'm trying to figure out how to add space above an algorithm2e algorithm. The algorithm is exceeding the margin, and I can't get it to move down with vspace. Its just the top bar that is exceeding the margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts              
     \overrideIEEEmargins
```

[image]

```
    \begin{algorithm}

\SetAlgoLined
\KwIn{Initial configuration $s$}
\KwOut{A sequence} 
Create tree \Tree{}\;
Create auxiliary\;
\While{$t$ not in \Tree }
{
\If{guiding iteration}
    {
    Find a node\;
    Create a new node\;
    \If{$n'$ is valid }{
        Calculate\;
    Insert $n'$ into \Tree{}\;
    }

    }
\Else
    {
    Generate a random;
    Find a node\;
    Create a new node\;
        \If{$n'$}{
    Calculate a configuration\;
    Insert $n'$\;
    }
    }
    Check to see\;
}
Generate a path\;
\Return $P$\;
\caption{WRRT*}
\label{ALG:Path}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble to see whether the columns are actually sticking outside the text block boundary. Can you also expand your current code to include the `\documentclass` you're using?

Comment: I added those changes you requested

Comment: I've created [this paste](https://pastebin.com/raw/NRSHfb6k) of your code snippets to make it into a minimal working example, just so I can replicate your output. However, it doesn't compile. Can you take the code I provided, update it and post it in your question so the community can replicate your issue? [Read this if you don't know what an MWE is](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764).